# Submitting application in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, appstore-approval

I'm having trouble submitting an application from the Xcode 4.

The situation: I developed an application for a client.  The app was developed in xcode3 and submitted almost a year ago.  I submitted it under my clients itunes connect account.

I recently did a minor bug fix and am now trying to submit the update.  When I try to validate or submit, I keep getting a "Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate." error.

When I try to submit, I use my client log-in credentials.
I've downloaded and installed a appstore distribution certificate from his account
I've downloaded and installed the provisioning profile for distribution
I choose the proper application and set the identity to iPhone Distribution:xx where X is the provisioning profile.

And that's it. I get the error and can't figure out how to get around it.  I read somewhere that there could be a problem with the project.pbxproj file where duplicate release profiles might be causing problems.  I looked and there was only one, I deleted it anyway so it would be rebuit.

Anyone have any thoughts? I'm tearing my hair out on this one.

Comment: While Archiving make sure you have selected the Distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Bah!  I fiddled and fiddled and am not sure what exactly I did but when I selected to "not re-sign" it validated and uploaded properly. I'm sure I tried that earlier

I, by all accounts, am not a bright person.  But dang Apple, you've got to be able to find a better way to do this.  Maybe when I get to the point where everything is done in xcode4 with the team profile it'll get easier, but I've wasted more time working through submission then I've ever spent on a particular thorny programming issue or bug.

Answer (score 1):

This was just happening to me and there don't appear to be any solid answers for it anywhere.

It took a couple hours of tinkering with Schemes and Configurations, but I **think** the problem is that the selected Code Signing Certificate was different between the project and the target.

Select the project in the Project Navigator pane, then in the middle of the window you should see your project name under "PROJECT" and the app name under "TARGETS"

If you select both the project and the app (cmd-click on both), then you should be able to get a side-by-side view of the Build Settings for both.  Make sure you have the same Certificate Selected.  My problem was that I had the Ad-Hoc selected for the project and Distribution selected for the app/target.